# Is there a way to disable audio recording function in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, voip, audio-recording

I'm making a VoIP app for iPhone. It's required to to forbid any form of audio recording for security reason. Is it possible to do so? If so, how to do it? Thanks a lot!

Edit: The app is not for jailbroken iPhones. However, private frameworks are permissible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your .h file -

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface recordViewController : UIViewController
        <AVAudioRecorderDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
    AVAudioRecorder *audioRecorder;
    UIButton *playButton;
    UIButton *recordButton;
    UIButton *stopButton;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *recordButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *stopButton;
```

In you .m file -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
   playButton.enabled = NO;
   stopButton.enabled = NO;

   NSArray *dirPaths;
   NSString *docsDir;

   dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
        NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
   docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
   NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
       stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

   NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

   NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary 
            dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
            [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], 
            AVEncoderBitRateKey,
            [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], 
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
            [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], 
            AVSampleRateKey,
            nil];

  NSError *error = nil;

  audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                  initWithURL:soundFileURL
                  settings:recordSettings
                  error:&error];
  [audioRecorder stop];
}
```

The last line `[audioRecorder stop]` is going to make sure the audio recording is stopped. You can do something similar to your app..

Comment: Although it's late to say, I tried this code with Voice Memos, and it doesn't work...

Comment: As far as I investigate, doing background recording while having a VoIP conversation is impossible, at least with non-jailbroken iphones. So there is no need to disable it for security purpose. This post is helpful. I'm gonna accept it.